# Is it items value or item values?

Tags: grammar

It's always confusing when double nouns and where to put the "s" to determine the plural? There's not proper rule. Especially in this case.
items value or item values?

Comment: If you look up "noun adjunct" or "attributive noun" you will find a lot of articles about this.  I think this question is likely to be closed as a duplicate, because we get a lot of questions about noun adjuncts on ELL.

Comment: What exactly is your term? An item of value?

Answer (score 1):

By 'double nouns' I presume you mean *compound nouns*.

As a general rule, you only pluralise the *principal* word of a compound noun. This is because a compound noun is still the name of one single thing and is treated as a single noun, so you pluralise the entire thing rather than every word in it.

The principal word in a compound noun is often the last word - for example, the principal word in '*garden shed*' is *shed*. The word 'garden' is really acting as an adjective and telling what *kind* of shed it is. So, the plural would be '*garden **sheds***', not '*gardens sheds*'. Likewise, in your example, the plural of '*item value*' would be '*item values*'. It is a value, not an item.

The principal word isn't always the last one - for example, the plural of '*brother in law*' would be '***brothers** in law*'.

There are some exceptions, for example "*children's clothes*", in the context of naming a department at a store. Both words are plural, but there would be no singular equivalent for this context.

Comment: Does this apply to many different types of item, it's still called, many item values, not many items value?

Comment: @Mallimika Yes. Just like sheds in many gardens would still be "garden sheds".